# Problem during state restore; when Flink job is submitted

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

We are getting the exception, copied at the end of this post. The exception is thrown when a new flink job is submitted; when Flink tries to restore the previous state.

Environment:

```
Flink version: 1.10.1
State persistence: Hadoop 3.3
Zookeeper 3.5.8
Parallelism: 4
```

The code implements DataStream Transformation functions: ProcessFunction -> KeySelector -> ProcessFunction. Inbound messages are partitioned by key "sourceId" which is a part of the exception stack trace. SourceId is String type and is unique.

```
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 109, Size: 10
Serialization trace:
sourceId (com.contineo.ext.flink.core.ThingState)
```

We have overridden "org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.ProcessFunction.open()" method
Any help is appreciated

Exception stack trace:

```
2021-01-19 19:59:56,934 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Checkpoint triggering task Source: Custom Source -> Process -> Process (3/4) of job c957f40043721b5cab3161991999a7ed is not in state RUNNING but DEPLOYING instead. Aborting checkpoint.
2021-01-19 19:59:57,358 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Process -> Sink: Unnamed (4/4) (b2605627c2fffc83dd412b3e7565244d) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:255)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeStateAndOpen(StreamTask.java:989)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$0(StreamTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:448)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:708)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for LegacyKeyedProcessOperator_c27dcf7b54ef6bfd6cff02ca8870b681_(4/4) from any of the 1 provided restore options.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:131)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Failed when trying to restore heap backend
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(FsStateBackend.java:529)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$keyedStatedBackend$1(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:288)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:121)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 109, Size: 10
Serialization trace:
sourceId (com.contineo.ext.flink.core.ThingState)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:761)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.deserialize(KryoSerializer.java:346)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.StateTableByKeyGroupReaders.lambda$createV2PlusReader$0(StateTableByKeyGroupReaders.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyGroupPartitioner$PartitioningResultKeyGroupReader.readMappingsInKeyGroup(KeyGroupPartitioner.java:297)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapRestoreOperation.readKeyGroupStateData(HeapRestoreOperation.java:293)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapRestoreOperation.readStateHandleStateData(HeapRestoreOperation.java:254)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapRestoreOperation.restore(HeapRestoreOperation.java:154)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:114)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 109, Size: 10
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.MapReferenceResolver.getReadObject(MapReferenceResolver.java:42)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readReferenceOrNull(Kryo.java:805)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:728)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:113)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Are you setting the operator uid as it is shown here (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/savepoints.html#assigning-operator-ids)?

Comment: Have you changed the structure of `ThingState` in a non backwards compatible way (removed or renamed a field?).

Comment: @Felipe Will check this documentation . Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov. No We havent removed the fields from ThingState. We have aded some fields into it and there are some inner classes those are a part oft this class. However,  if the fields are removed, is there a way to address such situation?

Comment: @vetal_king Yes, you need to write your own state serializer that supports these removals.